# UPDATE statement pyodbc set NULL value (instead of None) in sql server

Tags: null, pyodbc

I have code where I want to update certain entries in a database.
Some attributes can have a `NULL` value.

Let's look at following situation:

```
new_doc_name = doc_name (can be None or string value)

sql = UPDATE Documents SET DocName = new_doc_name WHERE DocID = doc_id
cursor.execute(sql);
cursor.commit()
```

When new_doc_name is `None`, the value in the database is set as `None`, but I want it to be set as `NULL`.

When doing the same for `INSERT`, the values are set as `NULL` instead of `None`, which I want. I can't, however, replicate this with the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a parameterized query:

```
sql = "UPDATE Documents SET DocName = ? WHERE DocID = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, new_doc_name, doc_id);
```

Comment: No way to make this work with f strings? Asking because if not I need to edit hard coded SQL queries and the corresponding execute statement.